# Get webserver configuration location from PHP extension in c++

Tags: php, apache, centos7

I have created my own PHP extension in c++ and am using Centos7 - php 5.6 version.
I wants to write the my extension debug log into the web server logging directory.We can get this from PHP by calling phpinfo() method.

[image]

from /etc/httpd location logs directory symbolic link with /var/log/httpd/
[image]

How can we get this Apache configuration location from my PHP extension in c++?

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - You should also make sure that you add the correct and relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you were able to parse the web server's configuration file in PHP, you wouldn't be able to create your own log file. Worker processes in web servers usually don't have permissions to create new files in the system log directory.

If you need to print debugging messages, generate them with `php_error()`. They will be passed to the web server for error logging.

Comment: Thanks for replying.So we can't create our debug log into webserver logging directory right..you mentioned system log directory i.e /var/log/httpd/ ?.. Actually I need to write my PHP extensions log into web server(can be httpd or nginx) error log file..Is this possible? if yes, how can we done this from my extension in c++?

Comment: Yes. Use `php_error()`. Messages printed with that function will be passed to the web server for error logging.

Comment: I tried with php_error(E_WARNING,"RINIT method called") in my extension inside of PHP_RINIT_FUNCTION(apm). But it doesn't print in the apache error_log.